# NumberFormat not found flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

Below code NumberFormat class is not found in 'package:intl/intl.dart' package

code : `NumberFormat heart = new NumberFormat("#,###", "en_US");`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Add `intl` to your `pubspec.yaml`

```
dependencies:
  intl: "^0.16.1"
```

Check for latest version at https://pub.dev/packages/intl

and then import following:

```
import "package:intl/intl.dart";
```

Answer (score 1):

your code should be: `NumberFormat heart = new NumberFormat("#.###", "en_US");`

(If you imported correctly, as comment above, you should put a point instead of a comma)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another efficient method to add a dependency.

In VSCode:

1. **`ctrl + shift + p`**
2. Type **`add dependency`**
3. Type the desired dependency, in this case, it's `intl`

By this way, it is much faster than the common way of opening a browser, going to pub.dev, searching for a package, and then copying the package name.